PostgreSQL repmgr slow initializing replica
I have two postgresql nodes, pg-0 and pg-1, master and replica.
They are running on different machines with a 25bg/s bandwidth, 8gb ram and an AMD Epyc processor.
Inside i have 6 dbs totaling 1.5gb, so nothing huge.
This is the docker-compose.yaml for pg-1, pg-0 is identical except for the REPMGR_NODE_NETWORK_NAME and REPMGR_NODE_NAME environment variables.
services:
  pg-1:
    image: bitnami/postgresql-repmgr:latest
    container_name: pg-1
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - '/home/crminformatica/backup/:/bitnami/backup/'
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=postgres
      - REPMGR_PASSWORD=repmgr
      - REPMGR_PRIMARY_HOST=pg-0
      - REPMGR_NODE_NETWORK_NAME=pg-1
      - REPMGR_NODE_NAME=pg-1
      - REPMGR_PARTNER_NODES=pg-0,pg-1
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  db-data:

When starting the replica node, repmgr runs a pg_basebackup, from what i've understand, but it takes 1 hour to complete, which is insane considering the amount of data I have.
I have tried to log the percentage of completion with this repmgr.conf, but it seems to do nothing.
restore_command_options = '--progress --compress=9'
log_level = DEBUG
log_file = '/var/log/repmgr/repmgr.log'

I have had the same problem with pg_basebackup (without repmgr) and I have tried compression and increasing the number of replica connections but it didn't change.
What can I do?
